# Differentiate nested self keyword in recursive instance methods

Tags: python, scope, self

So the template of my code looks like this :

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params #a dictionary
    
    def recursive_iteration(self, buffer):
        if buffer :
            #do something
            self.params['new_field'] = "new_value"

        else :
            for i in range(2): 
                new_params = self.params
                new_params['some_field'] = another_value #changing with i
                Foo(new_params).recursive_iteration(True)
```

The problem I encounter is that when `recursive_iteration` is called inside another `recursive_iteration` then there are two `self` variables that exist within a different (but nested) scope.

And during the second iteration of the for loop (i=1):
`self.params` has the field 'new_field' which means the outer scope self was the one modified.

Did i just flaw my code and should rework the model ?(I could go functional only but this is partially existing code)

My question is : Can I precise which `self` I want to be modified with regard to their scope?

EDIT : The issue comes from the shallow copy of self.params. All the time the same dictionnary is modified. It's not about the scope of the variables.
Change `new_params = self.params` to `new_params = self.params.copy()` to solve the issue.

Comment: Why not assign a copy? `new_params = self.params.copy()`

Comment: The "self"s (object instances) are independent but for both "self"s the "self.params" refer to the same object (dict, I guess).

Comment: You were right, I did copy the reference to the dictionnary and did only a shallow copy. That's where my problem comes from and it was not about the scope of the variables. Thank you.

Comment: This code might be too minimal. Why do you have only a single method (aside from `__init__`) instead of defining a regular function that takes different arguments when called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : The comments under my post solved the issue.

Gist of it : the issue comes from the shallow copy of self.params. All the time the same dictionnary is modified. It's not about the scope of the variables. Change new_params = self.params to new_params = self.params.copy() to solve the issue.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get a new nested scope is that you create a new `Foo` with `Foo(new_params).recursive_iteration(True)`

If you want this to be recursive, and call `recursive_iteration()` on the same object, then you need to call it this way:

`self.recursive_iteration(True)`

Comment: No what I wanted to do was instantiate a new object to call the function on it. The problem was solved in the comment above.

Comment: It's not really recursion if a different object is calling the method. The underlying *function* might be the same, but different `method` instances are involved.